# Removing UIButton from UITableViewCell

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I've got a problem with removing UIButton from a subclass of UITableViewCell. This button is added only if a cell is the first one in a table view. So it happens that this button can be nil or it can be a instance of the UIButton class. Moreover, as all these cells have the same identifier, there might be a situation when the first cell, with button, is moved below. Then, I need to remove this button.

I'm doing it in such a way:

```
if(callBtn != nil) {
    [callBtn removeFromSuperview];
}
```

However, it causes a crash of the Application.

I guess this issue can be overcome by using different identifier for the first cell and the others, and probably it's a better solution. However, I'd like to know what's wrong with this code or what I should be aware of while removing subview from a subclass of UITableViewCell.

@EDIT:
Here is the code where cells are being created:

```
NSString *ident = @"HistoryCell";
HistoryItemCell *cell = (HistoryItemCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:ident];
// If there is no reusable cell of this type, create a new one
if (!cell) {
    if(indexPath.row == 0) {
        cell = [[[HistoryItemCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault withCallBtn:YES reuseIdentifier:ident] autorelease];
    } else {
        cell = [[[HistoryItemCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault withCallBtn:NO reuseIdentifier:ident] autorelease];
    }
} else {
    if(indexPath.row != 0) {
        [cell removeCallBtn];
    }
}

History *history = [[[Store defaultStore] allHistories] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[cell setDataFromModel:history];
return cell;
```

Adding button code:

```
if(withCallBtn == YES) {
        callBtn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        callBtn.tag = CALL_BUTTON_TAG;
        [callBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(callBtnAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        // setting background, title, etc

        [self.contentView addSubview:callBtn];
        [callBtn release];
    }
```

Greetings,
Adam

Comment: show the code were you add the button. Most likely you overrelease it there

Comment: Where exactly is the code located, that you titled with "Adding button code"? And how does the removeCallBtn look like? 
I guess that you remove the button from its superview, which will release it, but do not set callBtn to nil. You will need to do either, retain callBtn before removing from its superview or set the variable to nil when removing it and re-create it when it is used again. Better post the full code here. There is some logical error somewhere. BTW, you do not use ARC, right?

Comment: Eventually, I created different identifier for the first row. That solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Your button is being retained by its' superview, and when you remove it from the view, it will be deallocated.  You need to retain it BEFORE you call removeFromSuperview if you want to keep it around (otherwise go ahead and set it to nil so that you don't reference it again after it has been deallocated).

Therefore, I would change your code to this:

```
if(callBtn != nil) {
    [callBtn removeFromSuperview];
    callBtn = nil;
}
```

If you actually want to keep the reference around (which is not what you have in your original code) then you would use this:

```
if(callBtn.superview != nil) {
    [callBtn retain];
    [callBtn removeFromSuperview];
}
```